# LINQ Query with EF6 using Lambda Expressions for Search Page

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm working on an MVC5, C# application. I'm using Entity Framework 6, with a database first approach.

The issue I am having is on my search page. I am coding it to allow the user to enter values in any combination of 4 input fields.

This is what I have for the search controller so far:

```
    public ActionResult SearchForApplicant(SearchModel model)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchButton) || model.Page.HasValue)
        {
            var pageIndex = model.Page ?? 1;

            var results = db.Applicants.Where(p => (p.RESP_FRST.StartsWith(model.FirstName) || model.FirstName == null)
                && (p.RESP_LST.StartsWith(model.LastName) || model.LastName == null) && (p.HOH_UPI.ToString().StartsWith(model.HOHUPI) || model.HOHUPI == null))
                .OrderBy(p => p.RESP_FRST);

            model.SearchResults = results.ToPagedList(pageIndex, RecordsPerPage);

        }

        return View(model);

    }
```

(db is the object of the model class inheriting from DBContext created by EF)

I've also created a search model:

```
    public class SearchModel
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Applicant")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string HOHUPI { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<Applicant> SearchResults { get; set; }
    //public IPagedList<> SearchResults {get; set;}
    public string SearchButton { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see here, the user can search by any combination of first name, last name, or UPI. However, I also need a way for the user to search by address or phone number. We have a contact info table in which the users current and previous phone numbers and addresses are stored (address having two columns in the database for each line and a separate column for cell, home, work). The primary-foreign key relationship between the applicant and contact info tables is HOHUPI.

I appreciate your help. I just need some direction with the lambda expressions --- perhaps the full LINQ syntax would be more readable. Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to include the info table? Is the info table a navigation property?

db.Applicants.Include(x => x.infotable).Where(p => (p.RESP_FRST.StartsWith(model.FirstName) || model.FirstName == null)
                && (p.RESP_LST.StartsWith(model.LastName) || model.LastName == null) && (p.HOH_UPI.ToString().StartsWith(model.HOHUPI) || model.HOHUPI == null) && (model.InfoTable.PhoneNumber...)
                .OrderBy(p => p.RESP_FRST);

Comment: It was not a navigation property, but I still managed to accomplish the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding on the top of my head and shortened for brevity..

Try this:

```
int page;
            bool pagePresent = int.TryParse(model.Page, out page);

            string firstName = string.Empty;
            bool firstNamePresent = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FirstName));

            var query = (from a in this.Context.Applicants
                         where (pagePresent || a.PageNum == page)
                         && (firstNamePresent || a.FirstName == firstName)
                         select new
                         {
                             a.PageNum,
                             a.FirstName,
                             a.LastName
                         });
```

And your query variable would now hold information on the retrieved data based on the search criteria.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a shot.